# 401 unauthorized when trying to insert (create) new table

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I am trying to use google-api-services-fusiontables-v1-rev1-1.7.2-beta apis to create new table from my Android application.
I am using the Account manager as described in the Tasks sample  and successfully can get token using  the scope (AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE) as "fusiontables".
However, when trying to use the service to insert a new table I am getting 401 unauthorized error.
        //Create Columns

```
   List <Column> coulmns = createColumn(3,basicCoulmn);  

//Create the table

Table table = createTable("TestTable","fusiontables#table","Description", coulmns);

//Call the service

service.table().insert(table).execute();
```

Here is the error:

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized

{

"code": 401,

"errors": [

```
{

  "domain": "global",

  "location": "Authorization",

  "locationType": "header",

  "message": "Invalid Credentials",

  "reason": "authError"

}
```

],

"message": "Invalid Credentials"

}

Can you please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `fusiontables` for `AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE`, what happens if you use `oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables`?

Comment: That's great, with this scope I can connect to the service. That was missing "oauth2:" Thanks for the tip!!!!